# Constructors Ordering

Tags: java, constructor

I am working on a project and I am wonder if the order of the arguments passed into the constructors matter. For example, if I created a program:

```
public class Test{
    int t3;
    String h;
    Test(int t1, String t2){
        t3 = t1;
        String h = t2;
    }
}
```

Would it matter I that I do:

```
Test t4 = new Test( "hello", 6);
```

instead of

```
Test t4 = new Test(6, "hello");
```

like the order in the constructor? Thanks!

Comment: Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: Yes it matters.

Comment: In the example above, the first argument has to be an integer, and the second has to be a string.

Comment: Constructors are chosen according to the [rules in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3). TL;DR: yep, there have to be same number, and they've got to be in the same order.

Comment: Imagine you had a constructor for a rational number, which took the values numerator and denominator?  Wouldn't you think that the order matters?

Comment: @DavidChoweller that's a subtly different case, because they are parameters of (presumably) the same type. In OP's example, the compiler *could* realize that the parameters need to be reordered, because there's only one of each type. It's just that the language doesn't allow that.

Comment: Point taken, @AndyTurner

Comment: @DavidChoweller but, it's because of cases where the order matters, like the one you mention, that Java doesn't allow it: it would just be more complexity in the language for minimal value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matters, just like it matters for any method call. What if you had something like this:

```
public SomeClass(int a, int b)...
```

If you did

```
new SomeClass(1, 2);
```

how could the compiler know that you *actually* meant for `a` to be 2 and `b` to be 1? The point being the only case where the compiler could possibly decipher what you intended is if all of your arguments are of differing types - in most cases the compiler couldn't possibly know what you intended to do.

Even if all of the types *are* all different, how does the compiler know that you passed them in a different order on purpose? For all it knows it's saving you from a mistake.

Note that some other languages, like C#, do allow you to pass parameters in differing order than what you specified, but you have to label them so the compiler can know which is which.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
public class Test{
  int t3;
  String h;
  Test(int t1, String t2){
    h = t2;
    t3 = t1;
    }
  }
```

But not that:

```
Test t = new Test(t2,t1);
```

Because when you call any method you need to respect parameters order. 
For real if you want you can do that (your code will compile and execute) but then you will have value switched.

Answer (score 1):

Yes...you have to respect the order of the parameter because the constructor will be expecting an Integer as first argument and a String as second argument; anything different from that may throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

yes, order matters but you can "overload", that means add another constructor that has the parameter list reversed like..

```
Test(String t2, int t1){
 this.Test(t1,t2);
}
```

..and as you see, you can call the first constructor inside and java will find the correct version to be used by the signature